# Links with images do not stay in middle

Tags: html, css

So, I got set of links set up like this. Apologies for bad names, but to keep it easy to understand, I chose to not to use real paths/names. However, all paths check out in when page is shown/used.

```
<nav>
     <div class="center">
         <a href="index.html" class="navigointi"> <img src="folder/image1.gif" alt=""> </a>
         <a href="page1.html" class="navigointi"> <img src="folder/image2.gif" alt=""> </a>
         <a href="page1.html" class="navigointi"> <img src="folder/image3.gif" alt=""> </a>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Now, I want each image stick to each other, so that they form a one long bar. With the current set up, they all line up in the middle of the page in one row. However... there are spaces in between each. Here is the CSS:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

a.navigointi
{
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

img.navigointi
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

However, if I designate images as navigointi class... they do stick together, forming a one long bar, but at the same time, it breaks the centering. All images float to left side of the screen. Even if I remove all content from the img.navigointi, so it becomes empty style, it still remains the same. If I don't give the images a class, they return to the middle, but once again with the spaces in between them.

Any idea what is causing the centering to break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r93nA/).

The line that removes the single space between the anchors is `font-size: 0px;`
(found on CSS-Tricks)

CSS

```
.center {
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 0px;
}

.navigointi{
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
img
{
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Just added font-size: 0px to .center and everything is good now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you should use `display: inline` instead of `float: left`.
Here an example : http://jsfiddle.net/YTn2b/